Product of a standard parabolic subgroup with the opposite one
Let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic group defined over an algebraic closed field. Fix a Borel subgroup $B$ and a maximal torus $T\subset B$. Let $\Delta$ be the set of simple roots. For a subset $\Delta_\gamma\subset\Delta$, denote by $P_\gamma$ the standard parabolic associated with $\Delta_\gamma$ and $P^{-}_\gamma$ be the opposite one.
Suppose now $\Delta_\gamma\cup\Delta_\mu=\Delta$, can we get $P_\gamma^{-}\cdot P_{\mu}=G$?

My first instinct was no, but this is kind of a pain to check, even for the non-trivial $\operatorname{GL}3$ case! \ Equivalent questions, the first suggested by a colleague to whom I mentioned the question: is $P\gamma^-\backslash G/P_\mu$ a singleton? Is your product closed?  Is it a group?  The first might be easier to check if we conjugate $P_\gamma^-$ to a standard parabolic; the last could conceivably be checked by grungy computations with Bruhat cells.

@LSpice Thanks!
